# C code compiles into strange instructions

Tags: c, gcc

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char *str5=malloc(10);
  *str5="xxxxx\0";
  printf("%s\n",str5);
  return 0;
}
```

compiles into the following assembly (using "gcc source.c"):

```
=> 0x555555555179 <main+4>:     sub    rsp,0x20
   0x55555555517d <main+8>:     mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14],edi
   0x555555555180 <main+11>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20],rsi
   0x555555555184 <main+15>:    mov    edi,0xa
   0x555555555189 <main+20>:    call   0x555555555040 <malloc@plt>
   0x55555555518e <main+25>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
   0x555555555192 <main+29>:    lea    rax,[rip+0xe6b]        # 0x555555556004
   0x555555555199 <main+36>:    mov    edx,eax
   0x55555555519b <main+38>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
   0x55555555519f <main+42>:    mov    BYTE PTR [rax],dl
   0x5555555551a1 <main+44>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
   0x5555555551a5 <main+48>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x5555555551a8 <main+51>:    call   0x555555555030 <puts@plt>
   0x5555555551ad <main+56>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x5555555551b2 <main+61>:    leave
   0x5555555551b3 <main+62>:    ret
   0x5555555551b4 <_fini>:      sub    rsp,0x8
   0x5555555551b8 <_fini+4>:    add    rsp,0x8
   0x5555555551bc <_fini+8>:    ret
```

edit-
To clarify, I'm not asking how to correctly copy or assign strings - I know how to do that. I'm asking WHY this particular set of instructions gets compiled in this way. The answer selected answers it well.
-end edit.

What actually happens:
So, on main+42, it loads $dl (the lowest byte of the ADDRESS of my string constant "xxxxx\0" into the address $rax points to, which is my variable str5. This ends up being just a garbage character, and the rest of the string constant is never copied. The compiler spits out the following warning which is probably pertinent, but I don't understand how:
`source.c:6:14: warning: assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]`

What I'm expecting to happen:
The string constant "xxxxx\0" is loaded into the address pointed to by str5. Then, the string pointed to by str5 is printed to the screen.
Why does gcc compile this code this way?

Comment: Learning C by jumping in and hoping for the best is a great way to have a very bad time, especially if you are coming from something like Javascript. You will end up making many assumptions that do not hold. Instead, pick any of the many books on learning the language and start from there.

Comment: Also, whenever you think the compiler is doing something wrong, it's a safe bet that the mistake is on your end.

Comment: Is there any reason why you include `\0` into the string literal? A 0 byte is added automatically to string literals.

Comment: No reason. I'm just messing around with every possible combination of strings, instructions, etc. that I can think of to see how they play together. I'm not trying to accomplish anything by this other than just understanding as much as I can.

Comment: @ski Like I said, you are making an invalid assumption: that messing around is a useful way to learn things about C. It isn't because of this thing called 'undefined behavior', which basically means that if you do things that are not defined by the C standard, your code might work, might not work, might cause a failure in some other part of your code in three weeks or something even nastier. Like accessing data past the end of an array or accessing a freed buffer. I was you once and wasted a ton of time, which is why I wouldn't recommend that path.

Comment: `*str5="xxxxx\0";` will not compile without warnings/errors, as you noticed. In fact it points out a severe bug. You could do yourself a favour and stop chasing bugs that the compiler has already found for you, by following this advise: [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565) In particular, use `-Werror`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in C  `*str5="xxxxx\0";` does not copy the string.

This operation is actually:

- taking the address of the string literal `"xxxxx\0"`
- converts this address to `char` (which is an integer)
- assigns the first character of the allocated by `malloc` memory with this integer value

When you print it, the first character is that integer in the character form. The rest of the characters are not initialized and this code invokes undefined behaviour.

If you want to copy the string literal you need to `strcpy(str, "xxxxx");` (the string literal will have null terminating character and you do not need to put it there yourself)
So the compiler is right and it is generating the code for the program you wrote.

Comment: "converts this address to char" That's not guaranteed to happen at all. You cannot assign a `char*` to a `char` - it's an invalid form of assignment. See 6.5.4 (constraints) _"Conversions that involve pointers, other than where permitted by the constraints of 6.5.16.1, shall be
specified by means of an explicit cast."_ Where 6.5.16.1 is the list of valid forms of assignment, this isn't one of them.

Comment: @Lundin mind the level.

Comment: What's that supposed to mean? If you mean the knowledge level of the OP, then they need to know that the code is invalid C, even if they don't need to know the dirty details. Pretending that implicit pointer to integer conversions exist in C isn't helping anyone learning the language proper.